# Test Bad encryption or signature

Tags: c#, email, mimekit

I have an application that is able to decrypt and/or verify signatures on emails. I want to be able to send an email to the box that this application monitors that has an invalid signature and one that has an invalid encryption to make sure that my error handling works. How would I go about sending an email that has these issues? I know that everything works as expected when I send correctly signed and or encrypted emails, but not sure how to do a true test of my exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to test a bad digital signature is to sign the message and then modify the text of the message afterwards.

E.g. do something like this:

```
var body = new TextPart ("plain") {
    Text = "This is the message body that we're about to sign and then modify..."
};

var signed = MultipartSigned.Create (..., body);

body = (TextPart) signed[0];

body.Text += "\r\n\r\nAnd now the message has been modified...";

message.Body = signed;

smtp.Send (message);
```